# How do I get credentials on the bitcoin network?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network-daemon, zap

I'm setting up an LND node so I can learn about Lightning Networks. I apparently need a set of user credentials so that I can connect to the network.

How do I get the credentials that I need to set this up? Is it possible for an average user who is just trying to learn about LND?

Ideally I would like to connect to the main net, so that I can connect my Zap wallet to it.

I have to fill in these values in the config:

```
bitcoind.rpcuser=bitcoind_rpc_user_string
bitcoind.rpcpass=bitcoind_rpc_password_string
```

Also can someone explain these settings to me:

```
bitcoind.zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:18501
bitcoind.zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:18502
```

Is 127.0.0.1 ok to leave for these values?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to fill in these values in the config:
>   `bitcoind.rpcuser=bitcoind_rpc_user_string`
>   `bitcoind.rpcpass=bitcoind_rpc_password_string`

These are user defined, and used to authenticate and communicate with your full node. There is no authentication to the network, anyone is free to join.

You’ll want to define a username and password in your bitcoind `bitcoin.conf` file, and then input them here so that lnd can connect to your node.

> Also can someone explain these settings to me:
>   `bitcoind.zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:18501`
>   `bitcoind.zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:18502`
>   Is 127.0.0.1 ok to leave for these values?

ZMQ allows lnd and bitcoind to exchange info through a socket connection (getting new info about blocks and transactions). If the nodes (lnd, bitcoind) are on the same machine you can leave the address as the localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: Also yes, my bitcoin full node and my LND node are running on the same machine. So I'm good with 127.0.0.1. Thanks again!